# Set global parameters in aws cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm building a complex application in AWS using Cloudformation.
My setup is the following: I'm going to use yaml files to define the stacks and corresponding json files which contain the stack parameters. Anyway there are parameters which are the same in multiple json files and I'd like to define them globally in one file/stack instead of having to update them in multiple files everytime they change.
What is the recommended way to set such global parameters using cloudformation?
Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly create one stack with command parameters, end [export their values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) from this stack. Then, in other stack, the parameter values would be accessed using [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html).

An alternative could be to store common parameters in SSM Parameter Store, and then use [dynamic references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) in your template to access them.